# osm2po: import multiple .osm files for disparate regions?

Tags: osm2po

Does osm2po support importing **multiple** OpenStreetMap files into the same Postgres/PostGIS database (i.e., to be used for routing)?

If yes, can the OSM files be for geographic regions that are **not** next to each other? For example, could I import something like NewYork.osm and SanFrancisco.osm into the same routing database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, since version 4.6.9 it's possible.

1. Convert NewYork and SanFrancisco separately, but use `cmd=tj` which processes phase 1 and 2 of osm2po's conversion chain only.
2. Don't forget to set a meaningful prefix parameter for both, e.g. `prefix=ny` for NewYork.
3. Use the same `tileSize` parameter for everything you are going to merge.
4. The steps above result in two directories you can transform into a third one. e.g.:

`java -Xmx1g -jar osm2po-core.jar cmd=m prefix=nysf ny sf`

where `cmd=m` is the merge command and `ny` and `sf` the source directories (paths). You can even use wildcards here, but I do not recommend it.

Finally proceed with the merged directory and call phase 3 and 4 with

`cmd=sp prefix=nysf`.

By the way, there is no difference whether the regions intersect or not. You can even merge NewYork-Detailed, SanFrancisco-Detailed and US-Motorways-Only or sth. like that.

Comment: Thank you *very* much for not just answering 'yes', but explaining how it can be done! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Merging creates `*.2po` files under newly created directory `nysf`. How can I import those files into database? Or how can I generate SQL like previously for each country?